# angularjs: http.post() executes successfully but doesn't post anything to server's file

Tags: angularjs, http, tomcat, post, tomcat8

I am completely new to

> Angularjs

and I should send a string from client to server using Angularjs.

I have a java application as a server and I deployed it using tomcat8.
 assume it's name is 'server.war'.

I created a file in ***/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/server/testpost*** and in angularjs application i use **http service** as below:

```
console.log("data is:");
console.log(this.href);
$http.post('testpost', JSON.stringify(this.href)).then(function(response){
    if(response.data){
         console.log('received data response successfully');
    }
    console.log('httpService successfully');
    console.log(response.statusText);
    console.log(response.headers());
}, function(response){
    console.log('httpPut failed');
});
```

but after running it, there is nothing in testpost file and output of console is:

> ```
> data is:
> http://192.168.6.131:8080/g/#/?key=Bjl6xfWZegV0fhCy3Tx6xAjxGKjkOkquMbgxXxNO5UIr
> httpservice Successfully
> OK
> {accept-ranges: "bytes", content-length: "0", date: "Sun, 29 Dec 2019 08:16:42 GMT", etag: "W/"0- 
>    1577607392000"", last-modified: "Sun,
>    29 Dec 2019 08:16:32 GMT", …}
> ```

So what's wrong with my code? why testpost file doesn't contain any character?

is there another way to send this string to a file in server?

Comment: try adding a die('---') and check it in your Network's response and see if you have that die or not?

Comment: @rahim.nagori where should I use die() function?

Comment: @rahim.nagori I think there is enough log to understand what is the problem and adding a die function doesn't make any advantages.

Comment: @milad Just to be clear, are you trying to write a file through a POST request? If so, I think you didn't get how and why is used. In this case, flag me up and I will write a proper answer to you.

Comment: Could you please share :
console.log(response.data)

Comment: @JordiVicens yes, I try to write through a file using POST request because the PUT request is block by some servers and on some websites they say I can use post instead of put request.

Comment: @milad I think what you should do is, on you backend (your java), create a function that receives a string and saves it into a file, then you create a trigger that reads the posts request variables. On your front end, you access that file and function through a POST request, sending alongside the string you want your backend be saving. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @rahim.nagori it's size is 0 bytes and so console.log(respnse.data) doesn't print any output.

Comment: @JordiVicens yes, I think you're right and I go to change my backend but I am just a bit wonder is there any way to edit(or upload) a file in server side without any backend processing?

Comment: @milad from my understanding, you cand send a file to your backend and then process it and save it, for example, or you can send data to your backend, process it and create it and save it. But without any backend processing.. Perhaps using an FTP connection you could achieve something, but I still would chose backend processing, so you have always a better controll of what you save in you server. I hope this helps you.

Comment: @JordiVicens thank you, backend processing solved by problem as you said.